# Entering keys into textboxes to automatically tab to the next box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a activation wizard, where one of the forms, I need the user to enter keys in to the textboxes.

I have managed to get it to work when a user pastes the entire key. However, the automatic tab to next box is a mystery to me.

```
namespace ActivationWiz
{
    public partial class frmEnterTicket : ActivationWiz.frmTemplate
    {
        public frmEnterTicket()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if a complete ticket was pasted and distributes it into all 5 input fields
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void edTicket1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (edTicket1.Text.Length > 5)
            {
                string[] temp = edTicket1.Text.Split('-');

                for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            edTicket1.Text = temp[0].Trim();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            edTicket2.Text = temp[1].Trim();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            edTicket3.Text = temp[2].Trim();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            edTicket4.Text = temp[3].Trim();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            edTicket5.Text = temp[4].Trim();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So here when the user copies and pastes the for example: B4G4F-TZQYJ-2DJDJ-47NZ3-4ZJ5Y
It just sorts itself out perfectly. 
However if the user is typing it individually, B 4 G 4 F... after the 5th character it does not move to the next textbox.

I have tried to add this in:

```
if (temp[temp.Length - 1].Length > 5)
{
    string t = temp[temp.Length - 1];
    t = t.Substring(0, 5);
    temp[temp.Length - 1] = t;
}
```

But it fails.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is check if the length of the text in the textbox is exactly 5. If it is, use [`.Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change the focus to the next checkbox

```
private void edTicket1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (edTicket1.Text.Length == 5)
    {
        edTicket2.Focus();
    }
    else if (edTicket1.Text.Length > 5)
    {
        ... // What you have
    }
}

...   // Repeat for other textboxes
```

You could also replace `edTicket2.Focus();` with `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")`. This will move focus to the control with the next tab index. So you would have to ensure that your tab indices are in the correct order

Comment: Thank you will try this and get back on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the next control by using " this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true); "

Just put the text change of the textboxes on the code below and it will work

I used the sender so it will work on all the textboxes.

```
    private void Key_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;

        if (TB.Text.Length == 5)
        {
        this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
        }
     else if (TB.Text.Length > 5)
     {
     // code
     }
    }
```